# c++ preprocessor location code::blocks?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, codeblocks

I have imported a project from windows to linux in code::blocks using the import function

Now I have a problem with the following code

```
#ifdef WIN32
#   ifdef A_EXPORTS
#       define A_SPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define A_SPEC __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#else
#  define A_SPEC
#endif
```

Even on linux the variable WIN32 seems to be set somewhere in the code::blocks project, but I can't find it. Any idea where to find these C/C++ preprocessor variables

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the code itself, project defines exist in

**Project** -> **Build Options...** -> **Compiler Settings** -> **#defines**

Note from the tree on the left that there are separate settings for the project as a whole and individual build targets.